Maximizing the smallest angle between a vector and a set of vectors.
Here is the description of the problem:
Assume you are given a set of vectors $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are independent.
You want to find a vector $v$ such that $v$ points as far away as possible from every other vector. I.e. the smallest angle between $v$ and any vector of $V$ is maximized.
I found this thesis published in 2019, which calls the problem "Spherical discrepancy". I have tried implementing the algorithm described in there, but it seems to struggle for the n=3 case, which is the only setting I care about.
I am looking for a simple way to get the optimal vector for this problem.

First, normalize your vectors so they have Euclidean norm 1. Call the vectors $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_k$.
Basically, you are looking for the vector $x$ of norm 1 that minimizes $\max_{i}a_i^Tx$.
We can write this as the following optimization problem:
$$
\min z\\
s.t. z\geq a_i^Tx \;\forall i\in \{1,2,\ldots,k\}\\
||x||_2= 1
$$
I am pretty sure that this is a semidefinite program, as these allow for constraints like $||x||=1$. There should be plenty of solvers that can solve them quickly, especially in low dimension (but it may take a bit of effort to rewrite the equations in the right format of the solver).

What is $z$ in the formulation?

@Makogan an extra variable. Thinking about it in hindsight, though, it should not be possible to solve it with a single semidefinite program: the feasible region is not convex. So maybe it's not so simple.
